# What is the name of this pattern?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

At first I called in the ISnapshotService, this is what it does

```
CountrySnapshot snapshot = snapshotService.CreateSnapshot<Country, CountrySnapshot>(country);
```

For this to work Country must look like this

```
public class Country : ISnapshottable<CountrySnapshot>
{
  public CountrySnapshot CreateSnapshot(ISnapshotService snapshotService) { }
}
```

and CountrySnapshot must look like this

```
public class CountrySnapshot : ISnapshotFor<Country> { }
```

I used the name "Snapshot" because I initially intended this service to create immutable snapshots of classes for an end-of-period snapshot of a system for accounting purposes.  However it has occurred to me that sometimes the result will not be an immutable snapshot, for example a StockLocation might create a StockAudit (which is not a snapshot.)

So, keeping in mind that this will no longer just create snapshots I need to come up with better names for these 3 interfaces.

1. ISnapshotService
2. ISnapshottable - Country implements this to indicate it can create a CountrySnapshot
3. ISnapshotFor - CountrySnapshot implements this to show it is created from a Country

Any suggestion welcome.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a lot like [memento](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/memento). Snapshot would be a Memento and Snapshottable would be an Originator that's outsourced its saving capabilities to a SnapshotService.

EDIT: Agreed, this is not memento, although the structure is similar. What it could be is a case of either [Temporal Object](http://martinfowler.com/ap2/temporalObject.html) or - what do you know - [Snapshot](http://martinfowler.com/ap2/snapshot.html).

Comment: It's not memento. I don't intend to restore the state from the new object back to the original object, and in some cases the object created will not be immutable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a factory pattern. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: If I am not mistaken the factory pattern creates new objects with their default state, whereas this pattern creates new objects with state based on another existing object.

Comment: Factories can do anything you want them to do. That has nothing to do with default states.

Comment: E.g. some "moronic" programmer wrote a class with lots of attributes but only one default constructor. You make a factory with factory methods that take the three or four typical arguments for which you else would need to call three or four setters.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more like a prototype pattern, because it creates new objects based on the state of an existing object.

I have gone for

1. IPrototypeService
2. IPrototype
3. IPrototypedFrom